# Limit IIS log file size from code

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-config

I have a web server hosted on IIS on AWS, recently one of my instances became unhealthy, the reason being the IIS logs have inflated to a massive size and filled up my entire drive.

Since I'd rather not change the actual image deployed on the EC2 service, I was wondering if it's possible to limit the size of IIS logs from code/web.config/etc - that way it will update whenever I upload a new version or open new instances for horizontal scaling.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that [IIS does not have a mechanism to clean up old log files by default](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/managing-iis-log-file-storage), so there's nothing you can add to the web.config to do this. If you IIS instance has write/modify access to the log folder, you could probably write something to delete the files that runs on app start-up/once a day.